# Не могу обновить Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 на Update 3

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Установлена `Visual Studio 2015 Update 2`.

С [сайта](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs)  скачиваю `Update 3`. Запускаю и вижу ошибку:

> Setup requires up to 10MB across all drives.

Кнопка Update не активна

На диске `C:/ 8Gb, D:/ 2Gb` (Visual studio утановлена на диске C)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалите полностью VS Update 2

> D:\vs_ultimate.exe /uninstall /force (D - путь к iso файлу)

Далее на сайте [visualstudio.com](https://www.visualstudio.com/ru/downloads/)  вы можете скачать `.iso` файл **Visual Studio 2015 с обновлением 3**